# What does DOD stand for in this indicator?

Tags: debt

I was looking at the indicator [External debt stocks, total (DOD, current US$)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/DT.DOD.DECT.CD) on the worldbank website and I don't understand what DOD stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for "disbursed and outstanding debt", which is explained [here](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/eds/Eng/Guide/file1.pdf), for example.